# How to remove webkit tap highlight border only?

Tags: css, ipad, webkit, highlight

If you don't like webkit to highlighting links when tapping them, you can remove that effect with:

```
-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgb(0, 0, 0, 0);
```

Actually I want this effect, but not the extra border added around the tapped element.

Is there a way to remove highlight border only?

Comment: -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent

Answer (score 3):

If you are talking about that orange borders around inputs on focus, you might want to try to add outline:none; to your CSS properties.

Like so :

```
input { outline:none; }
```

Answer (score 1):

a is missing

should be -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);